# Chrome does not show network traffic of Silverlight RIA services messages after update to version 32.0.1700.76 m

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

Couple days ago Google Chrome automatically updated from version 31.* to version 32.0.1700.76 m. After that happened it does not show in DevTools network traffic request/responses of "application/msbin1" type anymore. These requests are visible in all other browsers' dev tools (FireFox, IE) and in Fiddler, but not in Chrome. Also Chrome's popup menu in this version is very glitchy.
I don't see the way to downgrade Chrome to previous version. Please help I don't want to uninstall Chrome.

Network traffic does not even show resources (XAP file) a page loads.
Example:
http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/pixel-shader/demo/
This page loads file SilverlightShaderApp.xap, however dev tools of new Chrome's version never shows it in network tab.

I posted the question here, because it's developers question, not just chrome users.

I reported this issue on google chrome forum as well: [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/jY2VLOYlD-8/U91pTHyis_EJ).

Comment: I've been experiencing some troubles with the latest version of Chrome as well, unrelated to your problem, but I also would like to rollback, only links i found online were to the www.oldapps.com site which didnt work for me. My browsers color display is off, and the pages appear grayed out....

Comment: @A.O. You can get a 31.x release from http://download.oldapps.com/Chrome/31.0.1650.39_chrome_installer.exe (this installer is fully offline and does not contain any bloat. It's the kind of Chrome installer containing a "chrome.7z" file).

Comment: Possibly related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173844

Comment: @Rob W, Is there any link to official google web site? to make sure I'm not installing some tampered version with spyware on my PC

Comment: @PhilippMunin Verify the cryptographical signature on the .exe file to see whether it's tampered. To me, it shows "Google Inc.".

Comment: @RobW that link fixed all my problems! Chrome is running like normal, my display problems have vanished. I've been searching all morning about this and found nothing, I'm thinking it has to do with the recent update and that fact that my NVIDIA GeForce has been acting up lately and I'm unable to DL the latest driver, I'm chalking it up to a strange incompatibility with the new update and my current GC driver

Comment: I have the same annoying problem with the latest version of chrome, I also reported it to chrome team from report issue but no one has returned yet for 2 weeks.
Also buttons positions and usability of them on network tab is worser than the old versions. :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Flash

Comment: @RobW I suggest you make your comment the answer.  Apparently you just have to rollback to a previous version. or wait for the next one.

Comment: @Bob Elaborated my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly related bugs:

- [Issue 173844: Developer tools (Network section) don't show response of requests from flash applications](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173844)
- [Issue 335502:    XMLHttpRequests from Silverlight is not visible in devtools network tab](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335502)

To avoid the bug, you could downgrade to Chrome 31. A fully offline installer can be downloaded from http://download.oldapps.com/Chrome/31.0.1650.39_chrome_installer.exe.
If you downgrade Chrome, don't forget to [disable auto-update](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates). Also, "star" the relevant issues on Chromium's issue tracker so you'll receive email notifications for progress updates. When the issue is fixed, enable auto-update again.

Often, starting a new version of Chrome renders a profile unusable for older Chrome versions ("Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of Google Chrome."). When you see such message on start-up, either delete your old profile (don't forget to make a back-up!) (you can also try to delete some files, according to various users, deleting "Web Data" and "Web Data-journal" is sufficient), or launch Chrome with a new profile directory (`--user-data-dir=path\to\profile-dir`).
For more information on user profiles, see http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory.