# Chrome emulator tab defaulted on refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

With Chrome 32.0.1700.77 the new emulator tab is handy except it's the default tab when I refresh my page.

During my standard development workflow, I constantly refresh the page when I make changes.  I usually have the console window open at the bottom of the network or source views.  But every single time I refresh the page, the Emulators tab takes focus and I can't see the console.

This is truly annoying since the app will fail because of a simple JavaScript typo, but I can't see the console without clicking one more time (to focus the console tab).

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Combined with the [Chrome Developer Tools unresponsive since update 32.0.1700.76 m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184844/chrome-developer-tools-unresponsive-since-update-32-0-1700-76-m) issue, I would have to say Google really tripped up this release.

Comment: Work-around = find/report bug and downgrade? See notes at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21280687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a workaround yet.  It looks like there has been a bug reported to Google as found on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/g_93_bKmaiA), but no fix has come about yet.

I think the only way (right now) to prevent the console tab from being hidden when needed is to avoid using the emulator or revert to a previous version of Chrome.

Hopefully a fix comes soon!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this post was made, but I came across the same issue recently. When you have the developer toolbar open, the phone icon beside the "Elements" tab should be blue. Clicking that will disable Emulation.

source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/g_93_bKmaiA/SdHk0aXdEo4J